# Bash sort and join problems

Tags: sorting, join

I have to join two files. Firstly, I use commant sort and made two new sorted files. Next I use join, but it doesn't work.
My script:

```
sort  -t ',' -r -k 4,4 file1.csv > sortf1.csv
sort  -t ',' -r -k 1,1 file2.csv > sortf2.csv
join -t ',' -1 4 -2 1 sortf1.csv sortf2.csv > last.csv
```

And error:

```
join: sortf1.csv:7: is not sorted: df-77,I,red,6674,6
join: sortf2.csv:4: is not sorted: 1967,XS,34,nf-54
```

Comment: Maybe join doesn't understand reversed sorted files? Try without it, you can always do a sort -r last.

Comment: Join should understand. There are some lines in output file (last.csv). I tried use my script on the others files (created by me) and it work.

Comment: Show sample input and your desired output for that sample input.

Comment: file 1:(; is break line)
nb-26,IV,red,3630,5;
pv-63,IV,yellow,6303,2;
sj-90,IV,blue,1957,2;

file 2:
1951,XL,95,zw-13;
1972,M,48,zt-67;
1991,M,72,ok-15;
last:
df-77,1944,S,75,II,blue,1911,2;
df-77,1944,S,75,III,blue,3279,6;
df-77,1944,S,75,II,violet,5080,1;
df-77,1944,S,75,I,red,6674,6;